# Asp.Net MVC5 Linq query to check data in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to write a LINQ query which will check the data in a table against the value that that's being imputed by the user. The purpose of this is that a supplier will have a plan assigned to them which will contain the amount of time they have to complete against that user. This is done through the plan model and controller. Then the supplier has to complete there actual time they have completed against the user. At this stage the supplier is filling out a timesheet, so I wish to check to see if the time is greater than the time that has been allocated to them.

I have tried using the following query

```
 var Time = db.Plans.Any(s => (s.CustomerId == timeSheet.CustomerId) && ((s.Monday <= plan.Monday)));
```

But this dosen't seem to work

My Models are : Timesheet

```
  public class TimeSheet
{
    public int TimeSheetId { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/M/yy}")]
    public DateTime? WeekCommencing { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/M/yy}")]
    public DateTime? WeekEnding { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Monday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Tuesday{ get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Wednesday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Thursday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Friday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Saturday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Sunday { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer customer { get; set; }

    public bool CompletedTimeSheet { get; set; }
```

Plan Model :

```
public class Plan
{
    [Key]
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Range(typeof(TimeSpan), "00:00", "12:00")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm\:ss}")]
    public TimeSpan? Monday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Tuesday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Wednesday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Thursday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Friday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Saturday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Sunday { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int AgreementId { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public bool CustomerHasPlan { get; set; }
```

And the Timesheet controller:

```
    // GET: TimeSheets/Create
    public ActionResult Create(int? ID)
    {
        if(ID == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        TimeSheet model = new TimeSheet();
        // model.FullName = Name;
        model.CustomerId = ID;
        return View(model);
    }


    // POST: TimeSheets/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TimeSheetId,WeekCommencing,WeekEnding,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,CompletedTimeSheet,CustomerId,Total")] TimeSheet timeSheet, Plan plan)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var Monday_test = db.TimeSheets.Any(s => (s.CustomerId == timeSheet.CustomerId) && (s.Monday <= timeSheet.Monday));
            if (!Monday_test)
            {

                db.TimeSheets.Add(timeSheet);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }

            else
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }

        return View(timeSheet);
    }
```

Hopefully someone can see were I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "doesn't seem to work", what does that mean? Does it throw an exception? Does it return the wrong results? What exactly are you expecting to see, and what happens instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't seem to work"? Query is not returning correct information or some kind of runtime error?

Comment: It drops it to my else statement when I know that the value should be true. For instance monday has the value of 01:15 assigned to it, However if user puts the value in 01:15 it drops into the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really tell what the query is doing, but by looking at your query and comparing it to your models, you misspelled Monday as "Maonday".

Try:

```
 var Time = db.Plans.Any(s => (s.CustomerId == timeSheet.CustomerId) && ((s.Monday <= plan.Monday)));
```

Comment: @Neva sorry it should be Monday have amended